# Why is it bad, if an entity can save itself?

Tags: php, orm

with a few ORM I can see that:

```
$entity = new TableName();
$entity->setName('username');
$entity->setPassword('zxbvc');
```

**`$entity->save(); // bad!`**

with others, I see it this way round:

```
$entity = new TableName();
$entity->setName('username');
$entity->setPassword('zxbvc');
DoctrineManager::persist($entity);
```

the first one was explained as "not the object does something with itself but something happens WITH the object"

I dont get it, practically...

Comment: This us off topic for stack overflow as it's highly opiniated. It might be a better fit at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. In general it's about separation of concerns, and some don't want the object itself to know how, where and even if it's persisted.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't inherently bad. Each approach has its pros and cons. Google "active record vs data mapper" and use what works for you.